# how to implement popup java swing

Tags: java

i want to add java pop up dialog from system tray similar as gtalk application , avast vireus notification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [setPopupMenu()](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/TrayIcon.html#setPopupMenu(java.awt.PopupMenu)) method on the TrayIcon class.

Comment: i mean pop up dialog not menu . similar to gtalk when we get new mesage adialog from taskbar comes .

Comment: In that case you can simply create a new JDialog and set it visible when a new message is received.